# How I can pass data between screens in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to passing data between screen
and failed with

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'props.navigation.getParams')
```

My code:

First screen:

```
const ForgotPasswordScreen = ({ navigation, }) => {
  const [text, setText] = useState('');
  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput onChangeText={(text) => { setText(text) }}></TextInput>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { navigation.navigate('VerificationScreen', { phoneNumber: text }) }}>
         <Text style={{ color: COLORS.WHITE, fontSize: 16, fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Continue</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  )
```

And i'm try to receive data at second screen:

```
const VerificationScreen = ({ navigation, }, props) => {
  const phoneNumber = props.navigation.getParams('phoneNumber');
  return (
    <View>
       <Text>{phoneNumber}</Text>
    </View>
  )
```

Thanks so much !!

Comment: which version of react navigation you are using??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Output:

[image]

This full example should work:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

// You can import from local files
import AssetExample from './components/AssetExample';

// or any pure javascript modules available in npm
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const App = ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="ForgotPassword" component={ForgotPasswordScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Verification" component={VerificationScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

const VerificationScreen = ({ navigation, route }) => {
  const { phoneNumber } = route.params;
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{phoneNumber}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const ForgotPasswordScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [text, setText] = useState('');
  const handleInput = (event) => {
    let temp = event.nativeEvent.text;
    setText(temp);
    console.log(temp)
  };
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TextInput
        placeholder={'Input Text'}
        value={text}
        onChange={handleInput}
        style={styles.input}
      />
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() =>
          text
            ? navigation.navigate('Verification', { phoneNumber: text })
            : alert('Please Input the text')
        }>
        <View style={styles.btn}>
          <Text style={styles.text}>NEXT</Text>
        </View>
        <Text>{text}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    marginTop: 100,
  },
  btn: {
    width: 100,
    height: 50,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderRadius: 10,
    border: '2px solid black',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  input: {
    borderRadius: 10,
    color: 'black',
    width: 300,
    padding: 10,
    border: '2px solid green',
    marginVertical: 5,
  },
  text: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
});
```

You can find a full live example here: [Live Demo](https://snack.expo.io/@xeteke8423/passin_data_btwn_screens)

Comment: Thanks so much. This helpful and I solved my problem with your anwser ^^

Answer (score 3):

In react, `props` is the *first* argument of a function component.

In your example above, you attempt to access `props` in the *second* argument of the `VerificationScreen` function component (which would be `undefined`).

Also, you attempt to access `props.navigation` which would give you an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigation' of undefined

Instead, because you are already de-structuring `navigation` from `props` in the *first* argument of the `VerificationScreen` function component, you should use it to access the `navigate` method.

```
const ForgotPasswordScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [text, setText] = useState('');
  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput onChangeText={(text) => { setText(text) }}></TextInput>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { navigation.navigate('VerificationScreen', { phoneNumber: text }) }}>
         <Text>Continue</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  )



const VerificationScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const phoneNumber = navigation.getParams('phoneNumber');
  return (
    <View>
       <Text>{phoneNumber}</Text>
    </View>
   )
}
```

I highly recommend that you take some time to read [the react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html).

Answer (score 1):

in second screen you can change

```
const VerificationScreen = (route, navigation) => {
  const { phoneNumber } = route.params;;
  return (
    <View>
       <Text>{phoneNumber}</Text>
    </View>
  )
```